# Fetching Form Data Values using OOP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a Script to fetch the values of form data through OOP, I am not able to return and print the values. Here's my code.

I want to create dynamic Validations too, Using some dynamic PHP code and OOP using arrays.

this is my signup.php file

```
<?php
    include('inc/form-data.class.php');
    $signup_data = new FetchUserData;
    if(isset($_POST['signup']))
    {   
        $signup_data->FetchSignup('fname_prefix', 'fname', 'uname', 'key',
                                  'ckey', 'gender', 'pnumber', 'country', 
                                  'state', 'city', 'zpcode', 'website',
                                  'agreement');
    }
?>
```

This is inc/form-data.class.php

```
<?php
class FetchUserData
    {
        private $fname_prefix,
                $fname,
                $uname,
                $key_pass,
                $ckey,
                $gender,
                $pnumber,
                $country,
                $state,
                $city,
                $zpcode,
                $website,
                $agreement,
                $values;

        public function SignupValuesReturn()
        {
            return $this->value;    
        }
        public function FetchSignup($fname_prefix, $fname, $uname, $key, $ckey, 
                                    $gender, $pnumber, $country, $state, $city,
                                    $zpcode, $website, $agreement)
        {
            $this->fname_prefix = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$fname_prefix"]);
            $this->fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$fname"]);
            $this->uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$uname"]);
            $this->key_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$key"]);
            $this->ckey = $_POST["$ckey"];
            $this->gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$gender"]);
            $this->pnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$pnumber"]);
            $this->country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$country"]);
            $this->state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$state"]);
            $this->city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$city"]);
            $this->zpcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$zpcode"]);
            $this->website = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$website"]);
            $this->agreement = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["$agreement"]);
            $this->values = array(
                'fname_prefix' => $this->fname_prefix,
                'fname' => $this->fname,
                'uname' => $this->uname,
                'key_pass' => $this->key_pass,
                'ckey' => $this->ckey,
                'gender' => $this->gender,
                'pnumber' => $this->pnumber,
                'country' => $this->country,
                'state' => $this->state,
                'city' => $this->city,
                'zpcode' => $this->zpcode,
                'website' => $this->website,
                'agreement' => $this->agreement
            );
            return $this->values;
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: As a side note: dont use mysql_* functions because they are almost deprecated. Try PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an "s" missing from `$this->values`:

```
public function SignupValuesReturn()
  {
    return $this->values;    
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me how can I use those arrays values outside the class?

Comment: Since it's an associative array, simply like this: `$result = $signup_data->SignupValuesReturn();`, then you can use them like this: `$result['fname_prefix']`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)
Can you help me how to create a dynamic Validation with PHP and OOP?

Comment: What do you mean on dynamic validation?

Comment: Like without adding empty and etc, We just use the same thing to create validations.